# Max length of collatz sequence - optimisation

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, math, optimization

I'm trying to solve [this MaxCollatzLength kata](http://www.codewars.com/kata/53a9ee602f150d5d6b000307/) but I'm struggling to optimise it to run fast enough for really large numbers.

> In this kata we will take a look at the length of collatz sequences.
>   And how they evolve. Write a function that take a positive integer n
>   and return the number between 1 and n that has the maximum Collatz
>   sequence length and the maximum length. The output has to take the
>   form of an array [number, maxLength] For exemple the Collatz sequence
>   of 4 is [4,2,1], 3 is [3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1], 2 is [2,1], 1 is [ 1 ], so
>   MaxCollatzLength(4) should return [3,8]. If n is not a positive
>   integer, the function have to return [].
>
> As you can see, numbers in Collatz sequences may exceed n. The last
>   tests use random big numbers so you may consider some optimisation in
>   your code:
>
> You may get very unlucky and get only hard numbers: try submitting 2-3
>   times if it times out; if it still does, probably you need to optimize
>   your code more;
>
> Optimisation 1: when calculating the length of a
>   sequence, if n is odd, what 3n+1 will be ?
>
> Optimisation 2: when looping through 1 to n, take i such that i < n/2, what 
>   will be the length of the sequence for 2i ?

A recursive solution quickly blows the stack, so I'm using a while loop.  I think I've understood and applied the first optimisation. I also spotted that for n that is a power of 2, the max length will be (log2 of n) + 1 (that only shaves off a very small amount of time for an arbirtarily large number).  Finally I have memoised the collatz lengths computed so far to avoid recalculations.

I don't understand what is meant by the second optimisation, however.  I've tried to notice a pattern with a few random samples and loops and I've plotted the max collatz lengths for n < 50000.  I noticed it seems to roughly follow a curve but I don't know how to proceed - is this a red herring?

[image]

I'm ideally looking for a hints in the right direction so I can work towards the solution myself.

```js
function collatz(n) {
  let result = [];

  while (n !== 1) {
    result.push(n);
    if (n % 2 === 0) n /= 2;
    else {
      n = n * 3 + 1;
      result.push(n);
      n = n / 2;
    }
  }

  result.push(1);
  return result;
}

function collatzLength(n) {
  if (n <= 1) return 1;
  if (!collatzLength.precomputed.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
    // powers of 2 are logarithm2 + 1 long
    if ((n & (n - 1)) === 0) { 
      collatzLength.precomputed[n] = Math.log2(n) + 1; 
    } else {
      collatzLength.precomputed[n] = collatz(n).length;
    }
  }
  return collatzLength.precomputed[n];
}

collatzLength.precomputed = {};

function MaxCollatzLength(n) {
  if (typeof n !== 'number' || n === 0) return [];
  let maxLen = 0;
  let numeralWithMaxLen = Infinity;

  while (n !== 0) {
    let lengthOfN = collatzLength(n);

    if (lengthOfN > maxLen) {
      maxLen = lengthOfN;
      numeralWithMaxLen = n;
    }
    n--;
  }

  return [numeralWithMaxLen, maxLen];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your memoization with precomputed values works. You memoize `collatz(n)`, but only in the front end code, which you call once for each `n`. There is no chance of getting a memoized value. Your core function always interates down until you reach 1. It is here that you should make use of the precomputed values to cut the sequences short.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm memoising collatz calls inside collatzLength, to prevent the inner loop in collatz recomputing a collatz sequence.  I think this works as expected because when I first attempted it I naively memoised the actual collatz sequences and (unsurprisingly) ran out of memory!

Comment: You're constructing each actual Collatz sequence as an array and then taking its length, when all you need to record in `collatz()` is the length of the list so far and the current value on it (which you already have in `n`).  Even if appending to an array can be done in amortised constant time, this will still be a moderately large constant factor slower than just adding 1 to an integer!

Comment: As j_random_hacker said, you don't need to calculate the whole sequence, only the length. Memoization only pays off if you re-calulate things with the same input. You never do that. You call `collatzLength` `n` times, each time with a different value. Try removing the precomputed values and return `collatz(n).length` directly. I think you won't see a slow-down. The memoization belongs to the `collatz` function.

Comment: Also @MOehm makes a good point, which I'll try to rephrase: If you find that, say, `collatzLength(42)` is not already in the table of precomputed values, it's *not* usually necessary to calculate the entire sequence back down to 1 -- it's sufficient to keep calculating the sequence *until you hit some number that **is** already in the table of precomputed values*.  As soon as you hit such a number, you can just add its length to the length you have calculated "the hard way" so far.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you make this into an answer, I will gladly mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Regarding the comment about not recalculating the same input, MaxCollatzLength is invoked multiple times in increasing sizes in the test harness, so I do avoid some recalculations.  Evidently this is not paying off enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memoization is the key to good performance here. You memoize the end results of the function that calculates the Collatz sequence. This will help you on repeated calls to `maxCollatzLength`, but not when you determine the length of the sequence for the first time.

Also, as @j_random_hacker mentioned, there is no need to actually create the sequence as list; it is enough to store its length. An integer result is light-weight enough to be memoized easily.

You can make use of precalculated results already when you determine the length of a Collatz sequence. Instead of following the sequence all the way down, follow it until you hit a number for which the length is known.

The other optimizations you make are micro-optimizations. I'm not sure that calculating the log for powers of two really buys you anything. It rather burdens you with an extra test.

The memoized implementation below even forgoes the check for 1 by putting 1 in the dictionary of precalculated values initially.

```
var precomp = {1: 1};

function collatz(n) {
    var orig = n;
    var len = 0;

    while (!(n in precomp)) {
        n = (n % 2) ? 3*n + 1 : n / 2;
        len++;
    }

    return (precomp[orig] = len + precomp[n]);
}

function maxCollatz(n) {
    var res = [1, 1];

    for (var k = 2; k <= n; k++) {
        var c = collatz(k);

        if (c > res[1]) {
            res[0] = k;
            res[1] = c;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

I haven't used node.js, but the JavaScript in my Firefox. It gives reasonable performance. I first had `collatz` as a recursive function, which made the implementation only slightly faster than yours.

The second optimization mentioned in the question means that if you know `C(n)`, you also know that `C(2*n) == C(n) + 1`. You could use that knowledge to precalculate the values for all even `n` in a bottom-up approach.

It would be nice if the lengths of the Collatz sequences could be calculated from the bottom up, a bit like the sieve of Erathostenes. You have to know where you come from instead of where you go to, but it is hard to know ehen to stop, because for finding the longest sequence for `n < N`, you will have to calculate many sequences out of bound with `n > N`. As is, the memoization is a good way to avoid repetition in an otherwise straightforwad iterative approach.

Comment: You can do a bottom-up calculation (always move from i to 2i, and *also* whenever i has remainder 1 when divided by 3, you need to branch to (i-1)/3 -- so it's a tree), and knowing where to stop won't be a problem if you use breadth-first search (so that all length-1 sequences are found, then all length-2 ones, etc.), but this risks doing a lot of unnecessary calculation.  OTOH the memoised solution you give never does *any* unnecessary calculation :)

Answer (score -1):

In this task you are required to write a Python function,
maxLength, that returns two integers:
• First returned value: for each integer k, 1 ≤ k ≤ m, the
length of Collatz sequence for each k is computed and the
largest of these numbers is returned.
• Second returned value is the integer k, 1 ≤ k ≤ m, whose
Collatz sequence has the largest length. In case there are
several such numbers, return the first one (the smallest).
For example, maxLength(10) returns numbers
20 and 9
Which means that among the numbers 1, 2, 3,…, 10, nine has the
longest Collatz sequence, and its length is equal to 20.
In your program you may define other (auxiliary) functions with
arbitrary names, however, the solution function of this task
should be named maxLength(m).

Comment: Even when formatted intelligibly, this does not help understanding the second improvement suggested.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).